# Intellij json fragment problem with text block

Tags: java, string, intellij-idea, java-13

Pressing enter key in the intellij-2021.1 **Json Fragment** on **text block** causes to close json fragment and jump into code editor, but when working with **Json Fragment** on **regular text** there is not this issue.
Can someone help me why this happen?

Comment: Looks like a bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-267593

Comment: Thanks. This one is a scenario that cause to close **Json Fragment** when work on a **regular string**. but when working on **text block** in **Json Fragment** it happens in almost all scenario.